# How to create a "just show me all the data" Tableau report that displays all columns of all records

Tags: tableau-api

We want to have a set of reports: some include aggregations and trends. But one of them is "just show the raw data".  Here is what I see for just fifteen or so fields:

[image]

Now imagine the datasource has maybe 50 columns. It would be more than tedious to drag them individually.  Is there a way to bulk add all fields to a "just show me the data" report?

In response to a request for clarification:  I mean - just dump all the rows in a tabular format - like the `show()` on a `pandas` dataframe.

Comment: what do you mean by show me all data? I mean any constraint of rows and columns where they need to be placed?

Comment: I mean - just dump all the rows in a tabular format - like the show() on a pandas dataframe

Comment: To the extent I know you need to do it manually by selecting all at once

Comment: is there such a way to bulk select?

Comment: Select one by one using `Shift` key

Comment: Select in bulk by shift-clicking on the top measure, then shift-clicking on the bottom measure.  Multi-select individual measures by Ctrl-clicking them.

Comment: Huh - that's just normal selection that had not seemed to be working. I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

For investigation purposes, there is a button for showing all underlying data as it sits in the datasource.

[image]

Comment: Hi I'm interested in adding all the data to the report itself

Comment: Ah, that feature does not exist. Sorry. It would require manually dragging out each dimension and measure. (In fact, Tableau limits a crosstab to 6 dimensions wide by default unless changed manually.)